React nativ Error while updating property 'source' of a view managed by : RCTImageView
My project works fine in local PC, i run it with command : npx expo start
But when i try to test my application on my phone with expo go, command : npx expo start --tunnel -c
I have this error :
Error while updating property 'source' of a view managed by : RCTImageView

java.lang.double cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray

i have comment all my pictures, and try to connect with a simple file, but i have always this error
My index :
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Alert} from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
import {Picker} from "@react-native-picker/picker";
import 'intl-pluralrules'; // Polyfill pour Intl.PluralRules

const App: React.FC = () => {



    return (
        // <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>

            <Text>Test</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default App;

My layout :
    import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { TabBarIcon } from '@/components/navigation/TabBarIcon';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

export default function TabLayout() {

    return (
            <Tabs
                screenOptions={{
                    tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint,
                    headerShown: false,
                    tabBarStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: 'midnightblue',  // Change la couleur d'arrière-plan ici
                    },
                }}>
                <Tabs.Screen
                    name="index"
                />

                <Tabs.Screen
                    name="index_test"
                />

                <Tabs.Screen
                    name="index_profil"
       
                />


                <Tabs.Screen
                    name="index_c"
                   
                />

                <Tabs.Screen
                    name="parameters"
                   
                />
            </Tabs>
    );
}

I have delete all pictures and 'sources' i don't understand why i have "RCTImageView"
